# High Power Supply over a distance

Tags: power, transformer, power-engineering

I'm working on a project and have been stopped in my tracks part way through.

I am designing a system that will power an RC over a distance. So I have a generator, and around 300 meters of cable to a low power system. Since I want to use lighter wires I plan on ramping my voltage very high at the generator, passing it down the wires at a much smaller current, and then finding a way to transform the power down for usability, and then of course return. I dont care about power loss, if the system is only 50% efficient then its still successful.

My issue is that I cant find a way to make the power usable at the low end, without using a classic inductance transformer, which will weigh too much, (i only have about 2 kg to work with). Is there a basic concept that I'm missing for changing voltage at the low end? Also if it matters I need 2kW on my lowside to power my motors...

Comment: Use a higher freqency that way you can reduce the volume and weight of the transformers (for example the aircraft industry use 400 Hz instead of 50 ou 60 Hz as the standard in airplanes)

Comment: Making a 2kW VLF radio transmitter and long aerial seems unwise [tm}. You can feed DC at whatever voltage suits and convert it to lower V at far end with a high frequency power supply. | You don't way what "lighter wires" means to you.

Comment: I mean, if 50% power efficiency is good enough why not just use low voltage in the first place and accept the cable loss? You can easily measure the resistance of the cable to find out how much higher you need to compensate for the cable loss.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a higher frequency than the standard 50 or 60 Hz to reduce the volume and weight of the transformers (for example the aircraft industry use 400 Hz as the standard in airplanes).

Personally I'll don't go beyond a few kHz to avoid all kind of problems but it's just a rough estimation (and you might need a higher frequency than that to pass 2 kW with a 2 kg transformer), do the math to be sure. Also, if the frequency is relatively high for the wire thickness, think about using [litz wire](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Litz_wire) for the transformers windings, you lose on the volume but you win on the weight.

To drive the first transformer you can use a H-bridge (or even just a half-bridge with a center tapped primary on the transformer) and a crude astable since the efficiency isn't a concern. You can do better by approximating a sinus with multiple taps on the primary but it gets far more complicated.

On the other side, after the second transformer, just be careful about the switching speed of the diodes if you want to rectify the current (classic rectifying diodes might not be fast enough), use schottky diodes if you want to be sure to have no speed problem ever.

Answer (score 0):

COTS 2000W switching power supplies are available that weigh ~2kg. You could probably further lighten them in various ways (for example, by replacing the heavy steel casing with thin aluminum and getting rid of the mechanical bits that are required to fit into a server enclosure). If you converted to DC before sending the power down the wire you could reduce the size of the main filter capacitors by probably an order of magnitude.

That would give you a regulated voltage (say 12V) at the other end, with some tolerance for voltage drop at the input.

Just for an example, the DPS-2000BB, which can supply 164A at 12V and is rated for 200-240VAC in (so you could have 40V drop in the wires if you start with 240VAC). Also available cheaply on the surplus market.

[image: http://www.serveur-occasion.com/2151-thickbox_default/74p4452-alimentation-ibm-blade-center-74p4453-dps-2000bb.jpg]

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the other answers that higher frequency is a method to reduce your transformer size.

Sending higher frequencies down your light 300m cable might be a problem so you may be better off generating high voltage, rectify, then HVDC down the cable to a high voltage H-Bridge at the other end.

Another option is of course to build an HV buck converter.

Answer (score 0):

Feeding LF AC and so making a 2kW VLF radio transmitter with a long aerial seems unwise [tm]. Twisted pair helps stop this, but why start it?

As others have noted, you can feed DC at whatever voltage suits and convert it to lower V at far end with a high frequency power supply.

You don't way what "lighter wires" means to you.

Pload = 2000 Watt 
Stated acceptable efficiency = 50%.
So loss in line = 2000 Watt (total feed = 4000 Watt)
Load effective resistance at the far end converter input = line resistance for 50%loss in line, and Vdrop_line = Vload at inverter input.

Power loss = V^2/R   so
V = sqrt(Power x R)
For power = 2000 Watt
V = 44.72 x sqrt(R)
Say V = 50 R.

Wire tables are available in many places.
[**Typical wire table here**](http://www.daycounter.com/Calculators/AWG.phtml)

Using eg 17 AWG wire =~ 1 mm^2 of copper gives 0.0166 Ohms/metre .

300m length = 600m for 2 wires,
R = 0.0166 x 600 ~= 10 Ohms
V = 50 x sqrt(R) = 50 x 3.16 = 158V
That's the drop in the cable - so you'll need double that to provide an equal voltage in the load so feed voltage ~= 316V, say 300 VDC.
At the far end you will need to convert about 158VDC to what ever output voltage you need.

Sanity check.
I = V/R =~ 300/(10 + 10) = 15A. 
P = I^2R = 225 x (10 + 10) = 4500 Watt.  and
P = V x I = 300 x 15 = 4500 Watt.

So about right.

If you want lighter wire (see wire table) voltage will increase with sqrt (R).
Using 20 AWG = approximately half the area and twice the resistance per length will increase voltage by about sqrt(2) to about 425V.
I will drop in inverse proportion to V so here will be about 10.5A.

You'll need to check permissible and sensible dissipations and wire voltage ratings.

This is, of course, a dangerously dangerous way to do things and the chances of it easily meeting requlatory approval would be low.

If you increase wire cross section to say 10 AWG, 5.26 mm^2, 0.00328 Ohm/m, R is about 2 Ohms loop. V is about 65V across cable and as much again inload so 130V so above ELV in any sane society.

7 AWG 10.5 mm^2, 0.00163 Ohms/m,about 1 Ohm loop.
V cable ~= 45V and total with load about 90V.
You'd squeak into ELV category in some administrations.